# XenServer how can I shrink the virtual drive of XenServer domU?

Tags: virtual-machine, disk-usage, xen

How can I shrink the virtual drive of XenServer image?.

I gave 300Gb of space for one image (domU) and that was mistake. Now I want to shrink it. How can I do that?

The system is already set up and configured, I can't just start a new server. (But if there is no other way, I will.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bakytn,
Don't worry, I do this all the time! I'm always making huge VMs and then wanting to shrink them later. :)

For starters you will need to resize the partition inside of Mint.  Follow this excellent guide for resizing ext3:
http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions

You do not need to run this command: `tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sda1`; `resize2fs` now has full support for ext4 so you're good to go.

After you have resized the guest partition, shut down the VM.  Attach a new disk to the VM with the smaller size you want.  Boot the VM with a Linux boot CD, I'm a big fan of "Trinity Rescue Kit 3.4"

In Trinity lets assume you have the following:

```
/dev/hda    (good large disk)
/dev/hdb    (empty small disk)
```

At this point `hda` will have a smaller partition because you followed the guide above

Run `fdisk -l` to list all known partitions.  Then run `fdisk /dev/hdb` and create a partition table identical to `/dev/hda`.  Run `dd if=/dev/hda1 of=/dev/hdb1` for every partition that you have.

Now the final stage is to install the boot loader.  Follow the guide here:
http://tipstricks.itmatrix.eu/?p=291

After you are done, shut down the VM.  Eject the live CD ISO.  Detach but don't delete the large disk.  Click `properties` for the smaller disk, and choose the bottom menu item on the left.  For `device position`, change it from `1` to `0`.  Boot the VM and make sure that all your data is there.  For a final check you can run `sudo touch /forcefsck; sudo shutdown -r now` which will reboot the VM with a forced disk check at startup.  If everything is ok, delete your large disk image.

If you have any problems with these steps, let me know.  After you are done you should feel like a boss (cuz you are!).

Comment: Super! Will perform this operation on this weekend.

Comment: This goes without saying, but you should snapshot your disk before you start this! Always have a separate copy of your data when doing stuff like this!  Good luck! Let me know if you have issues!

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: do a backup first.

It depends on a number of things:

**1.** Is it an LVM ? (lots of `if's`)

**1.1** If it is a logical volume, and DOES NOT contain partitions (just a filesystem), and that `FS` is an `ext[2-4]` family, do an `e2fsck -f <device>` (without mounting it) to ensure filesystem consistency.

**1.2** run `resize2fs <device> <new size>`

**1.3** run `lvreduce` or `lvresize` on the logical volume to shrink it.

If the logical volume has partitions, then you'll have to play with `fdisk`/`parted` etc. AFTER you resized the `FS` with `resize2fs` and BEFORE `lvresize` or `lvreduce`. For a phisical disk, it is the same story, without the `LVM` commands. If you have another filesystem, look for the tools in your distro to resize it.

Comment: It is not LVM (I think, btw, how can I check?) just a standard Linux Mint 11 64 Bit (Debian based). It is ext4.

Comment: When you say "Drive of xenServer image", you mean the hipervisor (dom0) or a guest (vm) ? what is the device called ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the guest image (domU)

Comment: @bakytn no problem :). What is the device name ? (asigned into the disk parameter on /etc/xen/<domu cfg file>) ? That will give you an idea, or post it in here.

Comment: that's interesting..because there is no /etc/xen folder neither in XenServer itself nor in domU

Comment: I never used XenServer product, though I use Xen a lot ... perhaps XenServer has its config somewhere else :S

Comment: XenServer has to hide the information somewhere. From what I know XenServer always uses a LV as disk for a DomU.